# Request URL in Python

Tags: python, curl, solr, request

To trigger the update you have to visit a url in the browser. This script was made in shell to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash to initiate Solr Delta Import Handler

# Setup Variables
hostName=localhost
portNum=8080
SOLRPATH=/solr
SOLR='delta-import&clean=false'
STATUS='dataimport?command=status'
urlCmd='http://${hostName}:${portNum}${SOLRPATH}/dataimport?command=${SOLRCMD}"

# Operations
curl $URLCMD
```

I have tried to write this in Python, this is how far I got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Setup Variables
hostName='localhost'
portNum='8080'
SOLRPATH='/solr'
SOLRCMD='delta-import&clean=false'
STATUSCMD='dataimport?command=status'
urlCmd='http://${hostName}:${portNum}${SOLRPATH}/dataimport?command=${SOLRCMD}'

# Alternative to Curl {URLCMD}
```

So basically I have two questions:

1. Is my python code ok so far?
2. What is a simple alterantive to Curl in python? The event is normally triggered just by visiting the URL but I dont know how to do this in Python simply.

Comment: It's not really important for your code to work. But I really think you should use other naming conventions like PEP-8 suggests if you gonna write it in python: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, use one of these kinds of string formatting in Python:

```
urlCmd='http://{0}:{1}{2}/dataimport?command={3}'.format(hostName,portnum, SOLRPATH, SOLRCMD)
#or
urlCmd='http://%s:%s%s/dataimport?command=%s' % (hostName,portnum, SOLRPATH, SOLRCMD)
```

While there is [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) in python that uses libcurl, you should use a builtin module like `urllib2` to access the URL you generated if you want your script to stay portable.

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.urlopen(urlCmd)
```

Now there are several things you can do with your request:

```
req.close      req.fileno     req.getcode    req.headers    req.msg  
req.read       req.readlines  req.code       req.fp         req.geturl   
req.info       req.next       req.readline   req.url
```

While most of the methods are self explanatory, refer to the [urllib2 docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) for a detailed explanation of what they do.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is my python code ok so far?

No, its not. Please have a look at string formatting in Python.

Try this:

```
...
urlCmd='http://%s:%d%s/dataimport?command=%s' % (hostName, portNum, SOLRPATH, SOLRCMD)
```

> 1. What is a simple alterantive to Curl in python? The event is normally triggered just by visiting the URL but I dont know how to do this in Python simply.

Try the [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) module:

```
import urllib    
urllib.urlopen(url)
```

Comment: Is urllib included in python 2.7 or do I need to install it? Also, thank you for the hint on the string format

Comment: `urllib` is included with Python since version 2.3. So this should work for you.